# Simple sitemap news are always in pending state?

Tags: xml-sitemap

To site that is using Simple XML sitemap I installed Simple XML News Sitemap  module. Basically I cloned all the setting form existing sitemaps. Also configured article content type to use new site map variant. Problem is that Status page (/admin/config/search/simplesitemap) those new variant for news sitemap type are always in "pending" state.
I do have articles with this sitemap variant set, I was rebuilding sitemaps many times, and all other are re-generated well, but new one for news is always in pending state?

What can be the reason for that?
Using Simple xml news sitemap  8.x-1.0 and Simple xml sitemap 8.x-3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Pending' in this context means either no items have been queued (yet), or, all items from the queue have been skipped during generation. The latter happens if e.g. anonymous users lack permission to see those items (in your case: article nodes).

So please double-check that there are in fact URLs that are set to be indexed for that variant and that anonymous users can view those URLs.

If that's the case, I suggest opening up a support request in the [module's issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/simple_sitemap_news?status=All&categories=All).